# ORA-04023:could not be validated or authorized

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

When I m trying view for execution with any filter , this view successfully run/execute and data showing, but when I traying same view with date filter then showing error ORA-04023:could not be validated or authorized

```
SELECT * 
FROM V_XYZ 
WHERE UPDATE_TIMESTAMP >= to_date('1990-1-6 00:00:00 ','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
      AND UPDATE_TIMESTAMP < to_date('1990-2-7 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

error

> ORA-04023:could not be validated or authorized

I'm trying apply index, performance tunning. I need execute view with filter condition

Comment: Possibly causing the error, but your date format should be like `1990-01-06` not `1990-1-6`.

Comment: Make sure the object is valid (`alter view v_xyz compile`). If it is valid and you still get the error, this is corruption in the dictionary information in your shared pool. Try recreating the view. Then try flushing your shared pool (`alter system flush shared_pool`). If that doesn't work, try bouncing the database. If that doesn't work you may need a ticket with Oracle Support. You may have to run `@?/rdbms/admin/utldtchk.sql` or even rebuild the dictionary.